# Javascript same regular expression return different result

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a code as below:

```
var regexp = /((^\u002b[6][0]([1-9]{2}))|(^[0]([1-9]{1})))((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)(\d{3,})((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)(\d{3})(\d)?$/,
    str = '+60123456789',
    boo = 'false';

(!regexp.test(str)) ? boo = 'false' : boo = 'true';

console.log(boo);
```

I tested the code and the result returned `boo = 'true'` on this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/draashurx/t9ase2w1/) but `boo = 'false'` on my localhost.

Why is that? Is there anything wrong with my regexp code?

**EDIT :**

Thanks [@Cerbrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) and [@smnbbrv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990451/smnbbrv) for pointing out my weird ternary statement.

I corrected it but still getting different result in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/draashurx/t9ase2w1/1/) and my localhost.

```
var regexp = /((^\u002b[6][0]([1-9]{2}))|(^[0]([1-9]{1})))((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)(\d{3,})((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)(\d{3})(\d)?$/,
    str = '+60123456789',
    boo = 'false';

boo = regexp.test(str) ? 'true' : 'false';

console.log(boo);
```

**EDIT 2:**

I made a mistake at the previous jsFiddle. Corrected it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/draashurx/t9ase2w1/3/) but still getting discrepancy.

As requested by [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew), my regexp is to filter numbers. It should accept any number starting with either `+60` follow by any two number or `0` follow by any one number. The middle part is just to allow whitespaces and hyphens.

Apparently I also caused a minor fight between [@Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) and [@Newbee Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3481654/newbee-dev) (who I appreciate a lot for helping!). My str value is identical after checking. And localhost is indeed still showing different result.

**EDIT 3 :**

To [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282634/joe) : I ran my localhost using Microsoft WebMatrix 3, for that matters. And both instances are using the same browser.

**EDIT 4 :**

Thanks [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282634/joe) for his detailed examination of my regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604486/javascript-same-regular-expression-return-different-result/40605019#40605019). However, the discrepancy on my end still persists.

Updated the regexp according to his advice.

```
regexp = /((^\u002b[6][0]([1-9]{2}))|(^[0]([1-9]{1})))((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)(\d{3,4})((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)(\d{3})(\d)?$/;
                                                                                         ^
```

[New jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/draashurx/t9ase2w1/8/).

Comment: I'm not sure about your regexp but `(!regexp.test(str)) ? boo = 'false' : boo = 'true';` looks really weird. Use `boo = regexp.test(str) ? 'true' : 'false';` instead

Comment: @smnbbrv  thanks for pointing that out. But still, what made the result different? Sorry i'm just a beginner in both javascript and regexp.

Comment: yep ... boo is true on the fiddle ... perhaps you're doing it wrong on localhost

Comment: your jsfiddle gives the correct result

Comment: How are you running that on "localhost"?  Technically, the javascript in the jsfiddle is running in the browser on your local machine.

Comment: your format is invalid `+60123456789a` therefore the code is correct

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/t9ase2w1/2/ . i thing you are missing `!`

Comment: @NewbeeDev - assuming "true" is the correct result - because the new fiddle now says "false"

Comment: @JaromandaX they have different str values

Comment: FFS ... the original fiddle was like the code shown - the new fiddle has an `a` at the end of `str` ... comparing apples with paperclips

Comment: @NewbeeDev - yeah, I just saw that - what he's got on localhost is probably different again!!

Comment: @YongQuan check your str value if that is really a correct format. maybe you putted a different value

Comment: @YongQuan, scratch the discrepancy, I found a typo, fixed it and now everything returns true.  Windows, centos, jsfiddle all return true for me.

Comment: @ppovoski thanks for the update, sir. But may I know whether that's my regexp typo?

Comment: @YongQuan, No it was mine.  I copied `str` ending in 'a' to one os and `str` without 'a' to other os.

Comment: What happens if you use the actual plus and hyphen symbols (`\+` and `-`) instead of Unicode escapes?

Comment: @YongQuan maybe it's cache problem. try clearing your cache or opening it into an incognito

Comment: @AlanMoore the regex will break because `+` and `-` have their own meaning in regexp.

Comment: That's why I escaped the `+` (`\+`).  The hyphen doesn't need escaping, because it only has special meaning inside a character class (`[0-9]`).

Comment: Have you checked that the page source webmatrix is actually serving to your browser exactly matches the code in your fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You regex has a slight ambiguity.

```
/((^\u002b[6][0]([1-9]{2}))|(^[0]([1-9]{1})))((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)(\d{3,})((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)(\d{3})(\d)?$/
```

If we break this down one part at a time:

`((^\u002b[6][0]([1-9]{2}))|(^[0]([1-9]{1})))`
will match `+60` followed by 2 non-zero digits, or 0 followed by 1 non-zero digit

`((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)`
will match a single space,  a single dash or a dash surrounded by spaces, or nothing.

`(\d{3,})`
then matches 3 or more digits **<- This is where the ambiguity lies**.  Depending on how greedy the regex matcher is, this may consume to the end of the string if there are only digits left.

`((\s)|(\u002d)|(\s\u002d\s)?)`
repeat of before

`(\d{3})`
matches exactly 3 digits **<- if the previous pattern greedily matched** to the end of the string, this pattern will not match as all of the digits were consumed.

`(\d)?`
one digit or no digits

**tl;dr**
This regular expression is completely valid, but will give different results depending on the greediness setting of the engine that applies it.

Comment: Sir, your answer made a lot of sense. Hate to break it to you but... the localhost still showing `false` while jsFiddle is `true`.

Comment: it's still different after making the regex unambiguous?

Comment: unfortunately still different. Details in **EDIT 4**